# не работает массив в операторе IN

Tags: php, yii2

```
$ids = implode(',', $productsIds); //получается просто 2,3,4

$products = Product::find()
        ->where(['id'=>[$ids],'status'=>'1'])  //так не работает(выводит только первый товар)
        ->all();


$products = Product::find()
        ->where(['id'=>[2,3,4],'status'=>'1'])  //если просто подставлю числа , то все работает
        ->all();
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы массив вкладываете строчку. Надо так:

```
->where(['id'=>$productsIds,'status'=>'1'])
```

Имплод уберите.

Comment: не работает и так . Так там в запросе по-идее и должна вставлятся строка

Comment: С чего в запросе строка? Что у вас в var_dump($productsIds)

Comment: в многих примерах  видел как делали через implode. В var_damp у меня массив array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(4) }

Comment: спасибо , теперь все работает как надо